# What is the efficient way of get members for specific user in LDAP Query?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

In Active Directory, I have to use an LDAP query for getting members of a specific user. I am using the LDAP query format is,

```
userSearchFilter = (&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(sAMAccountName=user));
userSearchBase = user + ",DC=test,DC=COM";
userReturnedAtts[]={"tokenGroups"};

NamingEnumeration userAnswer = ctx.search(userSearchBase, userSearchFilter, userSearchCtls);
```

Comment: Do you mean "members of a specific group"? Are the `memberOf` attributes set?

Comment: Highlighted the code by using correct indentation.

Comment: @LutzHorn, Am asking about getting groups for a specific user? I am mentioned above the query will take 20 secs for the response.

Answer (score 1):

The [`tokenGroups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-tokengroups) attribute lists the SIDs of all the security groups (not distribution groups) that the user is a member of. If you want to get the *name* of the groups, you would have to look up each one. That's not very efficient.

It is also a computed attribute, which means that it is calculated at the time you ask for it. It is also a recursive list (if a user is a member of group A, and group A is a member of group B, the both group A and B will be in the list). That's likely why it takes so long.

Collecting all the membership for a user *can* be complicated, depending on your AD environment and what you're looking for. In the best case, you just have one domain that does not trust any other domain. In that case, you can use the [`memberOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-memberof) attribute of the user. That will contain both security and distribution groups that the user is a direct member of.

I mentioned this in my answer to your other question, but take a look at the article I wrote about this: [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html). The code examples are C#, but the principles apply to any language.

You might also benefit from reading my other article: [What makes a member a member?](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html). There are actually 3 ways a user can be considered a member of a group, although you will probably only care about one. But I also describe there when you would not want to rely on `memberOf`.